# Why can't I print the result from within the function?

Tags: python, function, printing

I'm working through the beginner's Python course in CodeAcademy. This is part of one of the exercises, where you're "checking out" at a grocery store, but I wanted to the code to print the final bill/"total" rather than just returning "total". I don't understand why it's not printing. I have tried putting it at the end, after the iteration, and, as here, within the recursion (before returning the total) to see if it'll print after each step. When I run this code, nothing displays.

```
shopping_list = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]

stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}


food = shopping_list

def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for item in food:
        if stock[item]>0:
            total += prices[item]

            stock[item] -=1
    print total
    return total
```

Edit:
These also aren't giving me a readout:

```
def compute_bill(food):
  total = 0
  for item in food:
    if stock[item]>0:
        total += prices[item]
        stock[item] -=1
  print "Total is $",total #tried 0-5 indentations, same blank result
```

Yet

```
def compute_bill(food):
  total = 0
  for item in food:
    if stock[item]>0:
        total += prices[item]
        stock[item] -=1
  print "Total is $",total #tried 0-5 indentations, same blank result
  return total

print compute_bill(food)
```

Returns

```
Total is $ 5.5
5.5
```

While - I did find a solution...

```
def compute_bill(food):
  total = 0
  for item in food:
    if stock[item]>0:
        total += prices[item]
        stock[item] -=1

  return total

print "Total is $",compute_bill(food)
```

Returns
    Total is $ 5.5
...but I'm confused as to why I can't just print the variable total, which should have been updated. And why it works there, but not as a feed in the function. This is just a question from an exercise, but I'm having trouble figuring out why it's doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example,

```
shopping_list = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]

stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}


food = shopping_list

def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for item in food:
        if stock[item]>0:
            total += prices[item]

            stock[item] -=1
    print total
    return total
```

You *define* a function `def compute_bill`. You never call that function. The function is executed iff it's called, e.g. `compute_bill(["banana"])`

Comment: Thankyou! This wasn't made clear in the tutorials, as they seem to mostly have us create functions without calling them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I quite understood the problem, but you said

> but I'm confused as to why I can't just print the variable total, which should have been updated.

If you try to print `total` from outside the function it will not work, since the `total` variable is only declared within the function. When you `return total` you allow the rest of your code to get the data from outside your function, which is why `print computeBill(food)` does work.

Edit, also if you want to print the total at each iteration, your code:

```
def compute_bill(food):
  total = 0
  for item in food:
    if stock[item]>0:
        total += prices[item]
        stock[item] -=1
        print "Total is $",total
```

Should definitely have this indentation, which means you'll print every time you iterate in the `for` loop (if you leave it as it was, it'll only print after the `for`).

Answer (score 1):

The print statement is the part of your function compute_bill(..), it won't be executed until and unless you call the function compute_bill(..).

```
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for item in food:
        if stock[item]>0:
        total += prices[item]
        stock[item] -=1
    print "Total is $",total #this works

compute_bill(food) # call the function it has the print statement
```